# Entity Framework Core Initial Create MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

I was working with a database in MSSQL and want to try out MySql 5.7.14.  I installed the mysql connector and ran:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

The result was

```
The property 'Records.Price' is of type 'decimal' which is not supported by current database provider.
```

So I tried, double and float.  Same issue.  I know that MySql supports these data types.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `Double` with capital `D`?

Comment: Can you post your dbcontext code and what version of .net core you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try another MySql EF Core provider?

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.MySql.EFCore/

More information about [EF Core Database Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/)